# Performing an internal redirect on Amazon CloudFront in a 4XX error handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We would like to serve several test domains off a single S3 bucket using CloudFront as a frontend.
Namely, `https://test-1.domain.com/index.html` goes to `bucket-1.s3.amazonaws.com/test-1/index.html`, `https://test-2.domain.com/index.html` to `bucket-1.s3.amazonaws.com/test-2/index.html` and so on.
The problem is that our web app is an SPA, so when there is no content in the S3 bucket we should return 200 not 404, say `https://test-2.domain.com/some/url` should get `bucket-1.s3.amazonaws.com/test-2/index.html` without modifying an URL (thus, 302 is not an option).
It would be perfectly possible using an Error Pages setting for a CloudFront distribution if we were serving just a single domain, but we need to distinguish between `test-1.` and `test-2.` and use `index.html`s from different subfolders. Is this still possible anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible using `Lambda@edge` Origin request Function.
This is how I would do it in complicated way:

1. Whitelist HOST header (I know we shouldn't do it for S3)
2. Write a `Lambda@edge` function to read HOST header values and 
   if it `test-1.domain.com`, choose the Origin with path as

   `bucket-1.s3.amazonaws.com/test-1/` else `bucket-1.s3.amazonaws.com/test-2/`

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/